# oracle instance total cpu usage percentage

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cpu-usage, percentage

I am trying to find the overall CPU usage of a oracle instance.I am currently using version 11.2 .Do we have any data dictionary view to fetch the over all instance CPU usage.i am able to get the CPU usage for each active session.Please could you kindly help me with query

Thanks
Pal

Answer (score 2):

You can try something along the following lines:

```
SELECT 'CPU_ORACLE'          TYPE,
       ROUND(value / 100, 3) COST_PERCENT_CORE 
  FROM v$sysmetric
 WHERE metric_name = 'CPU Usage Per Sec'
   AND group_id = 2
 UNION
SELECT 'CPU_OS'                                             TYPE,
       ROUND((percent.busy * parameter.cpu_count) / 100, 3) COST_PERCENT_CORE
  FROM
    (SELECT value busy
       FROM v$sysmetric
      WHERE metric_name = 'Host CPU Utilization (%)'
        AND group_id=2) percent,
    (SELECT value cpu_count
       FROM v$parameter
      WHERE name = 'cpu_count') parameter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below query

```
SELECT se.username, ss.sid, ROUND (value/100) "CPU Usage" 
  FROM v$session se, v$sesstat ss, v$statname st 
WHERE ss.statistic# = st.statistic# 
   AND name LIKE  '%CPU used by this session%' 
   AND se.sid = ss.SID  
   AND se.username IS NOT NULL 
   ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Chandrakant, Thanks for the reply.This query will give only the session level details,i need the overall instance level.